# yii2 API HTTP Basic Auth

Tags: php, yii2, auth

Пробую сделать тестовый REST API на yii2. В документации [указаны](https://nix-tips.ru/yii2-api-guides/guide-ru-rest-authentication.html) три базовых способа аутентификации. Решил попробовать HTTP Basic Auth. Но возникли проблемы и вопросы.

В документации указано, что в контроллере следует настроить поведения

```
use yii\filters\auth\HttpBasicAuth;

public function behaviors()
{
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
    $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
        'class' => HttpBasicAuth::className(),
    ];
    return $behaviors;
}
```

А после настроить метод `findIdentityByAccessToken()`, **но где?** В примере ниже для класса User

```
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;

class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {
        return static::findOne(['access_token' => $token]);
    }
}
```

Ну и более того, выходит, что всё это нужно писать в каждом контроллере для каждой модели. А если их 50? Дублировать одно и то же столько раз?
Как тут быть? И что не так? И где настроить метод `findIdentityByAccessToken()`? Всего лишь нужна общая авторизация на всё API в одном месте

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы не копировать это во все контроллеры, можно в конфиге приложения добавить событие и через него запретить использовать все без авторизации кроме отдельных эндпоинтов. Готовый код для config/web.php:

```
'as beforeRequest' => [
    'class' => yii\filters\AccessControl::className(),
    'rules' => [
        [
            'allow' => true,
            'actions' => [
                'login',
                'registration',
            ],
        ],
        [
            'allow' => true,
            'roles' => ['@'],
        ],
    ],
    'denyCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
        throw new \yii\web\UnauthorizedHttpException('You are not allowed to access this page');
    }
],
```

Comment: а как тогда залогиниться? Обращаясь к api я ведь должен передавать в заголовках к запросах ключ авторизации, тем самым подписывая каждый запрос. Или же следует создать отдельный контроллер для авторизации, отправлять туда данные для входы, проверять и авторизовывать?И потом в заголовках ничего не слать?

Comment: Как угодно. Можно использовать стандартный подход с кукой. Естесственно будет эндпоинт для входа, то есть для получения куки или токена. Кукой же вы тоже грубо говоря подписываете.